# Yii ListView Order By DESC

Tags: listview, yii

Im using Yii Framework

i want Show listView order ID DESC in Front USer

```
    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('to',$this->to,true);
    $criteria->compare('text',$this->text,true);
    $criteria->order='id DESC';
```

But Order ID DESC in my adminPanel so Not change Front User

Comment: You need to show more code. How do you use the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in the listView widget, you should also set a default sort in DataProvider.

```
return new CActiveDataProvider( $this, array(
  'criteria' => $criteria,
  'sort' => array(
    'attributes' => array(
      '*',
    ),
    'defaultOrder' => array(
      'id' => CSort::SORT_DESC,
    ),
  ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    At Controller :
    $data = Page::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id DESC'));
            $data = new CArrayDataProvider($data);
     $this->render('page', array(
                'data'=>$data,

    At View:

   <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(         

    'dataProvider'=>$data,
   'columns'=>array(
      array('header'=>'ID',
      'value'=>'$data->id',),
   ),
        )); ?>
```